# Is it possible to predict what number will computer choose randomly?

Tags: random

I'm trying to know what number the computer will randomly choose. Will I need a specific algorithm? Or do I need artificial intelligence?

Comment: How can you predict it if it is truly random? You might as well call the same random function twice, once for the prediction and a second time for the random number.

Comment: are you looking for pseudo-random algorithms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)?
Given a  known start value- the seed- the same squence of numbers can be generated over and over again. The resulting sequence looks random

Comment: Modern computers and programming languages use physical sources of randomness like reverse-biased diodes to feed entropy into RNGs to make them truly random, and therefore completely unpredictable. These random numbers are used for cryptography in critical applications like banking. All computers can also use simpler and faster--but less random--PRNGs for things like games. These can of course be predicted perfectly with perfect information, and can probably be cracked with some effort without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't predict a true random number, by definition, as it is random. Pseudorandom numbers can be predicted if you know both the algorithm being used and the seed number being provided.

https://www.howtogeek.com/183051/htg-explains-how-computers-generate-random-numbers/

Here's a good article on the different methods of generating random numbers.

Comment: so is it possible to know the seed or the algorithm ?

Comment: @osamasyr Technically yes. https://v8.dev/blog/math-random to see some info on JavaScript implementation of Math.random(). If you're using a library you could check the source code to see their implementation. If reading source code isn't an option, my answer would be it is mathematically possible, but I wouldn't have a clue where to start.